# Handle situation about phonecall with client

Tags: communication, phone, anxiety

**Background:**

A week ago, a coworker receive a email from one of the company's client. In that email they ask about review a "problem" with the results of a report - he didn't say which report exaclty.

I received this email monday this week. I checked it, but the email is very incomplete, barely says "no data at X day".

**Situation**

I approach to my boss and the coworker "who actually deals with the client" saying about the email was unclear and you should contact with them and asking more details = this info is not enough.

**Problem**

The main reasons about why I don't want and I'm not involved in client communication are:

- I'm working in other projects and in no other project I hadn't been asked about calling clients "via phonecall".
- They rarely are available and only in specific schedule *(which I don't know)*.
- Frankly *(and they know)*, I really don't like lie, make excuses or any related to handle clients.

Coworker listen me and gives me no answer and boss reply was "call X person" = the person who sended the "email" but neither the boss, coworker or even I had contact - this is *(it seems)* a final user of the reporting program I developed.

They basically dropped this ball on me. Boss don't really care and coworker is busy handling with other projects and clients.

How to handle this situation that doesn't involve:

- Search another job *(at least, not yet)*.
- Call this user/client.
- Compromise myself to call them.

**EDIT:**

My boss asked about if I call this user. I reply I didn't because I have to set a updated version but it needs testing - implementation of this program has not any negative impact in production, but the client who has the credentials for remote connection is not available and he it's hard to get callback only after a few days later.

I would like to learn what can I do for better my question - which I assure you, is a real problem I'm facing.

Comment: I would like to learn what can I do for better my question - which I assure you, is a real problem I'm facing.

Comment: Just call them?

Comment: Is not that simple, @Simon, they rarely are available and _for avoid getting this question more like a rant_ I don't feel neither conformtable and prepared for call them.

Comment: If you need information from them, there's no way around just contacting them, whether you do that through phone or email might not be that important. You not being comfortable doing that doesn't change this fact, nor is your boss likely to understand your discomfort.

Comment: @Simon your comment looks better in the answer section - I consider a good option. and "Dukeling" can you please clarify? I only understand about I'm not conformtable this doesn't change that fact - I'm not very fluent in english language.

Comment: Why don't you just email them? Why do you need to call them? Do you have their email address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything to do with customer complaints is best done in writing and carefully.

In your situation I would ignore the calling part and email the chap and ask politely for more information so I could troubleshoot better.

Comment: Agree. I'm more relaxed now and I send a email asking more information - politely of course. Thank you and, I think you have a typo: it's "chat" not "chap" - Google translator doesn't recognize this word. Upvoted but I don't have the enough reputation.

Comment: Chap = male person.  https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/chap

Answer (score 0):

Just try to call them and if they don't answer send an email to check, when it's a good time. Sometimes getting out of your comfort zone improves your capabilities. And if there are any issues during the call you are uncomfortable to answer, just say "I need to check this with my boss / coworker / whatever." Frankly I don't see what's the big deal and I'm not that great at making phone calls.

Comment: Not sure about how answer you about the "comfort zone" - but just for point out: anything related with handling customers are not my interest at all - even if that might cost my job.

Comment: I understand, I feel that way too. But you could see this a training to boost your self-confidence, which in my opinion is important no matter if you deal with clients.